# Python's time.sleep(1) finishes instantly

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I have a python function that does the following:

1. Start a new thread, and run in it a PyQt QApplication.
2. Do work for N seconds, and emit progress to the thread running the PyQt.

Now, before I start the PyQt QApplication, time.sleep() in the main thread works as expected, but after I start it, time.sleep(1) returns immediatly.

Here is an example:

```py
 def run_gui_thread(self):
    app = QApplication([])
    self.prompt = QDialog()
    self.ready = True
    app.exec_()
```

And:

```py
def do_work(self):
    print "Now is %s." % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time.sleep(1)        
    print "Now is %s." % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time.sleep(1)        
    print "Now is %s." % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Now is %s." % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

    self.thread = threading.Thread(target = self.run_gui_thread)
    self.thread.start()

    time.sleep(1)
    print "Now is %s." % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")        
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Now is %s." % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Now is %s." % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    time.sleep(1)
    print "Now is %s." % time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Output:

```
Now is 10:00:56.
Now is 10:00:57.
Now is 10:00:58.
Now is 10:00:59.
Now is 10:00:59.
Now is 10:00:59.
Now is 10:00:59.
Now is 10:00:59.
```

Any suggustions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a quick hack you might try `import select; select.select([], [], [], 1)` and see if it survives the signals better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the Qt stuff is using signals (including possibly `alarm()`) under the covers. As per the `time.sleep()` doco:

> Suspend execution of the current thread for the given number of seconds. The argument may be a floating point number to indicate a more precise sleep time. ***The actual suspension time may be less than that requested because any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine.*** Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.

You may be better off re-architecting your application so that you can use a [`QTimer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtimer.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your help!